# Telerik - RecurrenceRule - TryParse not working

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, recurrence

I am trying to parse recurrence rule string to telerik object but it does not work for me at all. The result is always null even though the string pattern seems to be right (passed from Kendo Recurrence control). Thank you for any thoughts on this.

[image]

Update: I tried another case to prove if the parse is working or not, here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this post http://www.telerik.com/forums/parsing-recurrencerule-server-side recurrence rule works when INTERVAL is specified.

> As to the exceptions thrown by RecurrenceRule.TryParse, I noticed that
>   it is caused when INTERVAL rule is missing. If you want to use the
>   RecurrenceRule.TryParse method, you will need to add it manually.

here is the modified code that was originally uploaded by jonno

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var start = today.AddDays(-14).AddHours(19);
var end = start.AddHours(2.5);

// Create a few recurring events using Kendo Web Scheduler and use the recurrence rules
var patterns = new[]
{
    "FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20140227T130000Z", 
    "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=3;UNTIL=20140227T130000Z", 
    "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=3;COUNT=4", 
    "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=5", 
    "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE;INTERVAL=1",
    "FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=5;BYDAY=TU,WE;INTERVAL=1",
    "FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=4;COUNT=5;BYDAY=WE,TH,SA", 
    "FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=3;UNTIL=20140331T090000Z;BYDAY=WE,TH,SA", 
    "FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=13;INTERVAL=1", 
    "FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=7;BYDAY=1FR;INTERVAL=1", 
    "FREQ=MONTHLY;UNTIL=20150212T130000Z;BYDAY=SU,SA;BYSETPOS=-1;INTERVAL=1",
    "FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=12;BYMONTHDAY=25", 
    "FREQ=YEARLY;COUNT=3;BYMONTH=2;BYMONTHDAY=28", 
    "FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=20200306T130000Z;BYMONTH=8;BYDAY=3WE",
    "FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=5;BYDAY=MO;INTERVAL=4",
    "FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=2;BYDAY=MO;INTERVAL=1",
};

// Now figure out which events will trigger in the next week - server side only - using Telerik.Web.UI.dll RecurrenceRule class.
foreach (var expr in patterns)
{
    var rrule = string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}\r\nDTEND:{1:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}\r\nRRULE:{2}", start, end, expr);
    try
    {
        RecurrenceRule recRule = null;
        var b = RecurrenceRule.TryParse(rrule, out recRule);
        if (recRule == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PARSE ERROR: " + expr);
            continue;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PARSE ERROR: " + expr);
    }
}
```